# Django: How to test that data has loaded into a database?

Tags: django, django-1.8

I am running a Django 1.8 site with a large database behind it (it's basically a GUI on this database). I have some management commands to load the full dataset into the database.

This is quite an involved process (since the dataset is large, and setting up involves creating materialized views etc). So once it's done I want to test that the data has loaded correctly into the database.

For example, I might test that there are the right number of rows in total, and that various sample queries give the results I expect.

Is there an expected place in my Django project to do this?

It feels a bit different from either unit tests populated by fixtures (it's the real, large dataset), or functional tests to check that the front-end gives the expected results.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Right now my thinking is that I should create another management command to run these test queries.

Comment: I answered you below, but still this feels weird to me, how often do you need to load the data again into the database? Are you talking about uploading multiple sets of data or the same set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to check it just after you populate database with this test data (at the end of management task, script etc)? You can implement it as a separate pytho script/function and call when it is required.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is by saving a state in a table in the database, you can create a table that holds the jobs that are run on the database, each job with a state, this way in your command that starts loading the data you can insert a new row there with the state as `started` and at the end you can change the state to `finished`, and in other places of your code you can check if there is a `started` job on the database then the data is not yet complete.

One caveat here you need to take care of is when something goes wrong while loading the data, you need to change the status to `failed` maybe, and store some logs about it, then you will need to check up on it later.